# Ubuntu 16.04 Flickering Problem

Tags: boot, laptop, 16.04, usb-installation

I have a system 76 Lemur laptop on which I have installed Ubuntu 16.04. My screen has started flickering. I thought it was a problem with the installation so I made a boot able USB and reinstalled. It was fine for a little, but has started to flicker again. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware problem? Does the same happen with different screens, different Ubuntu releases or different operating systems? Please [edit] your question to include your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: The problem was fixed after a few software updates. Thanks for the notice